# How to coverage more than 90% in test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I got 88% for this apex class, but i want morethan 95%.how to achieve this?please help me.

apex class:

```
public class Rfleet_Financial_Informations
{
    public List<RFLEET_Account_Protocol__c> contt{get;set;}
    public List<EditableContact> myAssociatedContact{ get; set; }
    public Integer editableContactNumber{ get; set; }
    public Boolean refreshPage {get; set;}
    public String id;
    String protocolname;

    public Rfleet_Financial_Informations( ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl )
    {            
        id=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');    
        myAssociatedContact = new List<EditableContact>();            
        Integer counter = 0;
        RFLEET_Protocol__c conn=[select name from  RFLEET_Protocol__c where id=:id];
        protocolname=conn.name ;
        contt=[select Name,Rfleet_Id_Alcor__c,Rfleet_Street_name__c,Rfleet_Street_number__c,Rfleet_City__c,Rfleet_State_Province__c,Rfleet_Zip_code__c,Rfleet_Country__c from RFLEET_Account_Protocol__c where Rfleet_Protocol__r.name=:protocolname];    
        for(RFLEET_Account_Protocol__c myContact :contt)
        {
            myAssociatedContact.add( new EditableContact ( myContact, false, counter ));
            counter++;
        }
    }
    public void deleteRowEditAction()
    {
        try{
            myAssociatedContact.get( editableContactNumber ).editable = false;
            delete(myAssociatedContact.get(editableContactNumber ).myContact );
        }catch(Exception e){}
        refreshPage=true;
    }

    public class EditableContact
    {
        public RFLEET_Account_Protocol__c myContact{ get; set; }
        public Boolean editable{ get; set; }
        public Integer counterNumber{ get; set; }            
        public EditableContact( RFLEET_Account_Protocol__c myContact, Boolean editable, Integer counterNumber )
        {
            this.myContact = myContact;
            this.editable = editable;
            this.counterNumber = counterNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest 
public class Rfleet_Financial_Informations_Test {
    @IsTest(SeeAllData=true)
    Static void Testfinancial(){
        RFLEET_Account_Protocol__c myContact = new RFLEET_Account_Protocol__c ();
        Boolean editable; 
        Integer counternumber;
        Boolean refreshPage;
        Integer editableContact;
        Integer counter;
        Rfleet_Financial_Informations.editableContact wra= new Rfleet_Financial_Informations.EditableContact(myContact, editable, counterNumber);
        RFLEET_Protocol__c pro = new RFLEET_Protocol__c(Name='john');
        insert pro;
        pro.Name = 'john';
        update pro;
        System.debug('Before Query');
        RFLEET_Protocol__c myfina = new RFLEET_Protocol__c();
        myfina = [select id,Name from RFLEET_Protocol__c LIMIT 1];
        PageReference vfpage = Page.Rfleet_Financial_Informations;
        System.test.SetCurrentpage(vfpage);
        Apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().put('id',myfina.id);
        Apexpages.StandardController sc = new Apexpages.StandardController(myfina);
        Rfleet_Financial_Informations fintest = new Rfleet_Financial_Informations(sc);
        fintest.deleteRowEditAction();                
    }        
}
```

Comment: What are the lines that you are not able to cover?

Comment: Hi Mark   these two lines are not covered in for loop in above apex class for(RFLEET_Account_Protocol__c myContact :contt)
          {  myAssociatedContact.add( new EditableContact ( myContact, false, counter ));
            counter++;
        }
    }

Comment: It's probably that your query that is getting assigned to `contt` is coming back with no elements.

Comment: how to do this one,please suggest me

Answer (score 1):

The for loop is not getting covered because there is not value present in `contt` variable which indicates there is no record in `RFLEET_Account_Protocol__c` object with condition `Rfleet_Protocol__r.name=:protocolname`. So you need to insert the record in your test class which satisfy the condition.

I have modified your test class to include the insertion of the required record.

```
@isTest 
public class Rfleet_Financial_Informations_Test {
    @IsTest(SeeAllData=true)
    Static void Testfinancial(){
        RFLEET_Account_Protocol__c myContact = new RFLEET_Account_Protocol__c ();
        Boolean editable; 
        Integer counternumber;
        Boolean refreshPage;
        Integer editableContact;
        Integer counter;
        Rfleet_Financial_Informations.editableContact wra= new Rfleet_Financial_Informations.EditableContact(myContact, editable, counterNumber);
        RFLEET_Protocol__c pro = new RFLEET_Protocol__c(Name='john');
        insert pro;
        pro.Name = 'john';
        update pro;
        System.debug('Before Query');
        RFLEET_Protocol__c myfina = new RFLEET_Protocol__c();
        myfina = [select id,Name from RFLEET_Protocol__c LIMIT 1];
        // Start - Added for covering for loop
        myContact.Rfleet_Protocol__c = myfina.id; // Assign Id of myfina to Rfleet_Protocol__c field of myContact
        insert myContact; // Insert myContact;
        // End - Added for covering for loop
        PageReference vfpage = Page.Rfleet_Financial_Informations;
        System.test.SetCurrentpage(vfpage);
        Apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().put('id',myfina.id);
        Apexpages.StandardController sc = new Apexpages.StandardController(myfina);
        Rfleet_Financial_Informations fintest = new Rfleet_Financial_Informations(sc);
        fintest.deleteRowEditAction();                
    }        
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I your **'Contt'** list you are taking the **RFLEET_Account_Protocol__c** record where **Rfleet_Protocol__r.name=:protocolname**. And you have this line **protocolname=conn.name ;** which means that **protocolname value equals the name of the RFLEET_Protocol__c record.**

So in your test class you need to first insert the **RFLEET_Protocol__c** record with some name consider "Dummy Name" . Then you will have to insert **RFLEET_Account_Protocol__c** record with the same name i.e "Dummy Name" . Then only your condition will satisfy which you have in the SOQL.

Regards!
Ruchika